# Is this proper usage of the word "talks about"?

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms

We were on the subject of borders within the EU/Europe; we were not talking about the actual EU and Europe borders.

> Europe and the EU are two different things. "Europe has open borders"
>   works as a sentence but talks about more countries than "EU has open borders".

Is *talks about* usable in the way it is used here?

This is for casual conversation.

Comment: You'd be better off recasting your first sentence for better clarity. "Talks about" is not that apt for this context. You might try, for example, "Europe and the European Union are two different things. The statement 'Europe has open borders' is somewhat accurate, but it also comprises more countries than the statement 'EU has open borders.'" In your second example, I'd add the word "two" before "different," and "The statement" before "Europe has . . ." and also before "EU has . . .."

Comment: I would say no. If you use it in a different way... such as Europe talks about France, Germany, Spain...etc. Doesn't really seem to work. Europe encompasses (from your use) or Europe references more countries... seems more proper... but I have no legitimate academia to support this... just doesn't seem right. (completely opinion)

Comment: "Europe references" does indeed sound more proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine in casual conversation, if you are understood. But if the hearer gave you a hard time about it, then it probaly was better to have used one of the more accurate suggestions such as "includes" or "refers to ". Because strictly speaking, a name for a group of countries doesn't talk about anything; only a statement, argument, thesis, philosophy, etc., could be formally said to "talk about" something.

You could say, however, "saying 'Europe has open borders' is talking about (or speaking of) more countries than saying 'the EU has open borders' "

Comment: Wouldn't "talks about" be correct then, since it is a statement, or what would you otherwise define it as?

Comment: Now that you mention it—sure, why not!  So, if anybody gave you a hard time about it, offer them that defense.

Answer (score -1):

If you are attempting to differentiate, I would say Europe and the EU ***refer to*** two separate things.  This word works in both formal and colloquial settings.

To assist the rest of your conversation, the difference lies in *what* they define or describe.  *Europe* is a continent, while the *European Union* is political-economic union of individual countries.  Switzerland is in Europe (geographically speaking), but not a member of the EU (politico-economically speaking), for instance.